# solve a equation in matlab with variable

Tags: matlab, equation

i'm trying to use 'solve' method to solve equations in matlab , i have a matrix which Coefficients of the variables are in it called 'A'

but when i use solve method with this code (i want A(1,1) to be the Coefficients  for x variable) :

```
W0 = solve('A(1,1)*x+13*y-16*z=1','13*x-10*y+13*z=0','-16*x+13*y-7*z=0')
W0 = [W0.x W0.y W0.z]
```

i dont get the correct answer and it shows me this for answer:

```
[ 11/(11*A(1, 1) + 185), 13/(11*A(1, 1) + 185), -1/(11*A(1, 1) + 185)]
```

meaning the Value of A(1,1) is not recognized in code, can anyone help me getting right answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
W0 = solve([num2str(A(1,1)),'*x+13*y-16*z=1'],'13*x-10*y+13*z=0','-16*x+13*y-7*z=0')
```

Comment: @Alireza.pir how about now?

Answer (score 2):

Using `solve`,

```
W0 = solve(strcat(num2str(A(1,1)), '*x+13*y-16*z=1'),'13*x-10*y+13*z=0','-16*x+13*y-7*z=0');
W0 = [W0.x W0.y W0.z]
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid `solve`, and use `\` instead.

```
W0 = ([A(1,1) 13 -16; 13 -10 13; -16 13 -7]\[1;0;0])'
```

Comment: thanks but for some reasons i have to use the `solve` method!
is it possible for solve method to do the right job?

Comment: See my second answer.